# Is it possible to send an SMS message with Twilio based on data from a MongoDB document and then update the document based on user response?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twilio

I am working on a little pet project where users can create a Goal and they will receive daily reminders of said goal using the Twilio API. Part of the Goal schema is phoneNumber which I store for the Twilio API. Currently my node server fires a helper function called initialMessage whenever a new document is created in my remote MongoDB database. initialMessage takes the goal as a parameter and has access to all of its data.

I want to add another layer of complexity and be able to ask the user via Twilio if they completed their goal today and based on whether they say Yes or No, update a nested responses object in the Goal schema that is { yes: 0, no: 0 } by default.

I set up ngrok and can handle SMS messages to a url on my express server, but I am having a hard time conceptualizing the flow for this to work, because I would need to retain the _id of the Goal that is sent from the initial message while waiting for a user response so I can call an updateOne function on my mongoDB cluster. Is this possible?

```
//Initial Message
const initialMessage = (goal) => {
  console.log(`+1${goal.creatorPhoneNumber}`)
  const messageBody = `Hi ${goal.creatorName.split(' ')[0]},
                       Thank you for setting a goal on Goaly!

                       We will send you a daily reminder for ${goal.goalTitle} starting on ${moment(goal.startDate).format("MMMM Do YYYY")}.`

  client.messages
  .create({
     body: messageBody,
     from: '+xxxxxxxxxx',
     to: `+1${goal.creatorPhoneNumber}`
   })
   .then(message => {
     console.log(goal._id);
   });
}


//Goal Schema
const goalSchema = {
  _id: String,
  creatorName: String,
  creatorPhoneNumber: String,
  goalTitle: String,
  goalDescription: String,
  dailyAction: String,
  noteToSelf: String,
  createdOn: String,
  startDate: String,
  endDate: String,
  creatorResponses: {
    done: {
      yes: Number,
      no: Number
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Could you look up the goal by the `creatorPhoneNumber` instead of the `_id` when you receive the incoming message from your user? You'd likely want to create an index over `creatorPhoneNumber` to ensure it is performant.